# I'm using "classList.toggle" to show and hide the nav bar by adding/removing classes. Is there any way to animate the "exit" animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

Thanks for stopping by.

**The issue:**

[Closing the navbar doesn't have an animation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6N5I.gif)

**How the animation for opening the nav bar was made:**

*1. Using Javascript to toggle classes.*

With each user click, it adds/removes class 'change' for the menu icon, and class 'expand' for the nav bar list.

```
    (function unhideNav() {
        let mobileMenu = document.querySelector('.mobile-menu');
        let hiddenNav = document.querySelector('.mobile-menu__list');

        mobileMenu.onclick = function () {
            mobileMenu.classList.toggle('change');        
            setTimeout(() => {
                hiddenNav.classList.toggle('expand');                    
            }, 70);                  
        }
    }());
```

*2. Using CSS transitions to animate the menu icon, and keyframe animations to animate the nav bar list.*

Menu icon animation:

```
.change .mobile-menu__1 {
    transition: all .5s $cubic;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.change .mobile-menu__2 {
    transition: all .65s $cubic;
    opacity: 0;
}

.change .mobile-menu__3 {
    transition: all .5s $cubic;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Nav bar animation:

```
&-item {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: var(--theme-grey-1);
    font-weight: 300;            
    padding-top: 1rem;  
    padding-left: 1rem;    
    padding-bottom: 1rem;          
    transition: all .1s;  

    animation-name: listItemAnimation;            
    animation-duration: .22s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;            
    animation-iteration-count: 1; 

    @for $i from 1 through $menuItems {
        &:nth-child(#{$i}) {             
            animation-delay: #{$i * 0.155}s;     
        }
    }
}

.expand { 
    animation-name: expandAnimation;
    animation-duration: 1.05s;
    animation-timing-function: $cubic;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;  
}

@keyframes expandAnimation {
    0% {    
        transform: translateY(-50rem);
    }

    100% {        
        transform: translateY(0rem);
    }
}

@keyframes listItemAnimation {
    0% {    
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(1.08) translateY(-1.55px);
    }

    100% {        
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1) translateY(0px);
    }
}
```

**So, when user closes the nav bar, JS removes the new classes from the menu and nav bar list, hence that's why there's no animation.**

I have been trying to find a way to create an "exit animation", but to no avail.

**My intended "exit animation" (make the nav bar disappear by moving it back up!):**

```
transform: translateY(50rem);
```

Please kindly offer suggestions and help.

Thank you so much! :)

Comment: show html code please (menu part ) and i wil show you a sample code here.

Comment: Thanks! :) 

HTML: https://paste.pydis.com/acajesicom.py

Although I made it kinda work with delayed animations, but it seems like a cop out. Please advise. https://paste.pydis.com/relopajayi.py

Comment: $cubic; and   &-item {  or   @for $i from 1 through $menuItems {  are nor CSS. I need something consistant to build your example

Comment: so what ever, look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53604507/ok-so-how-do-i-make-a-function-to-check-if-an-animation-passes-a-certain-point/53605512#53605512  __ using setTimeout (or toogle) will never work

Comment: Apologies, I'm using Scss to compile my CSS... what would be a better way to show you my code?

Comment: Why should I get your code, do the transformation from scss to css, then try to put all this code in a temporary page by adding the missing elements to make a test model and check the veracity of my code?  Please use the [code] button to something usable to work on it.